# Restrict keyup function from firing ajax after reaching the input max length

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

**Description:**

I have the following code which fires an ajax request to validate the typed promo code from a MySql DB table ....

The input field `$(#code)` has a max length of **5** characters

When I type 5 characters, which is the max length, in the input field the ajax call occurs and the validation process goes fine ..

---

**Problem:**

My problem is that when I keep pressing any additional key after those 5 characters are already typed, the ajax call keep firing with each key press ... which is incorrect.

Is there any possible way to restrict the `keyup` function with a change in the input value??

I another words, **only fire the ajax call once when the user typed 5 the five characters and never call it again unless he changed the input value**

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {  

        //the min chars for promo-code
        var min_chars = 5;  

        //result texts  
        var checking_html = 'Checking...';  

        //when keyup  
        $('#code').keyup(function(event){ 
            //run the character number check  
            if($('#code').val().length == min_chars){  

                //run the check
                check_code(); 

            }
        });  

    });


    //function to check the promo code  
    function check_code(){  

        //get code  
        var code = $('#code').val();

        //use ajax to run the check 
        $.post("promo_code_php/promo_code_check", { code: code },  
            function(result){  

            //do something ...

            }
        });  
    }

    </script>
```

The HTML Input field ....

```
<input type="text" id="code" name="code" maxlength="5" placeholder="Promo Code">
```

Comment: I don't think that would be wise @TinyGiant, mostly because if the user changes the value, like deleting the last char and then adding another one, it wouldn't trigger any ajax call.

Comment: Yeah I guess that was malformed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just keep a track of the input you have already checked. If the code is not changing, prevent firing up `check_code` function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

    //the min chars for promo-code
    var min_chars = 5;  
    var checked_input = "";  

    //result texts  
    var checking_html = 'Checking...';  

    //when keyup  
    $('#code').keyup(function(event){ 
        //run the character number check  
        if($('#code').val().length == min_chars && $('#code').val() != checked_input){  

            //run the check
            checked_input = ($('#code').val(); 
            check_code(); 

        }
    });  

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The above doesn't work more than once... here's how I would do it... it might be a little more complicated for your flavor though.

In your HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="code" name="code" maxlength="5" data-checked="false" placeholder="Promo Code"/>
```

In your jQuery:

```
$("#code").keyup(function() {

  if ($("#code").val().length === 5 && !$("#code").data("checked")) {

    $("#code").data("checked") = true;
    check_code();

  }

  if ($("#code").val().length < 5 && $("#code").data("checked")) {

    $("#code").data("checked") = false;

  }


});
```

This code guarantees to re-check if they, say, typed the wrong character or something.

Comment: the above code worked fine with me !! ... @14bmkelley